# Glade checkButton always returns false

Tags: python, gtk, glade

I'm trying to get the status of my checkbox when I click a button. However, it always prints False regardless of if the box is ticked or not. How can I have it check if the box is ticked?

```
builder = Gtk.Builder()
builder.add_from_file("GUI.glade")      
checkButton = builder.get_object("checkButton")

def on_submit(self, button):
        status = checkButton.get_active()
        print status
```

Comment: You must be missing something obvious. Can you post a [mcve] that shows your problem?

Comment: Here is an example of a GtkToggleButton , which is pretty much the same: https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/button_widgets.html#togglebutton